# echo don`t show when use unset global variables

Tags: php, session, echo, unset

I have started a session on config page, then `$_SESSION['logged_out'] = 1;` and on index page that:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_out']))
{
     echo "You have been logged out !";
     unset($_SESSION['logged_out']);
}
```

But the echo not workig, like unset is before him. And i don`t understand why, please help me.
EDITED:
Config page:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
include 'functions.php';

$logged_in = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    $username = sec($link, $_SESSION['username']);
    $password = sec($link, $_SESSION['password']);
    $udata = get_row($link, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username= '$username' && Password= MD5('$password')");
    if(isset($udata['ID']))
    {
        $logged_in = 1;
        if(isset($_GET['logout']))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            $_SESSION['logged_out'] = "1";
            mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE accounts SET rpgon = '0' WHERE Username = '$username'");
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Index page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_out']))
{
    echo "You have been logged out !";  
    unset($_SESSION['logged_out']);
}?>
```

This is it ...

Comment: what do you get when you say `var_dump($_SESSION)`? Do you see `logged_out` there?

Comment: anyway I'd reverse the logic there to have a var `logged_in` and check if it's still there.

Comment: Does *anything* show? Are you getting any errors in the log?

Comment: i don`t have any errors, the error reporting is activated.

Comment: Show the part where you have `set` the session?

Comment: You are not showing enough code for anybody to know whats really going on. SHow all the relevant code. Like the fact you include a `config.php` and that there is a `start_session()` in that included file.

Comment: Oke man, i edited post.

Comment: not, it`s same thing

Comment: somebody else who can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

If `echo` doesn't show anything is because the `if` condition is evaluated to `false`. This mean that `$_SESSION['logged_out']` isn't set.

Comment: variable is set, if remove that unset run perfectly but i want to resset that variable ..... and not work as i want. I want to show that message just one time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `start_session()` on every page that uses the `$_SESSION`. In fact if you are using $_SESSION anywhere in your site, its best to start it on all your pages.

So add `start_session()` just after the first `<?php` to ensure it is always started for all pages

```
<php
start_session();

 . . .

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_out']))
{
     echo "You have been logged out !";
     unset($_SESSION['logged_out']);
}
```

***Added after additional info given***

I think this may be one of your problems

```
$udata = get_row($link, 
                 "SELECT * FROM accounts 
                  WHERE Username= '$username' 
                     && Password= MD5('$password')"
                 );
```

The `&&` should be `AND`, then this query should return a result. You should really be checking the result status from all query command like so:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

ob_start();

include 'connection.php';
include 'functions.php';

$logged_in = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    $username = sec($link, $_SESSION['username']);
    $password = sec($link, $_SESSION['password']);
    $udata = get_row($link, "SELECT * FROM accounts 
                             WHERE Username= '$username'
                               AND Password= MD5('$password')"
                     );

    // this would have shown the error in the sql query
    // if it had been here before
    if ( ! $udate ) {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
        exit;
    }


    // now this if will be executed
    // although this if is probably no longer required
    if(isset($udata['ID']))
    {
        $logged_in = 1;
        if(isset($_GET['logout']))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            $_SESSION['logged_out'] = "1";
            mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE accounts SET rpgon = '0' WHERE Username = '$username'");
            header('location: index.php');

            // you should also follow a header() call with an exit;
            exit;
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: i have this in config.php the page where is the configurations and i use this in every page like includes.

Comment: Why the DownVote. I answered this before the OP told us that he had used  `start_session()`. Suggest deletion by all means, but a downvote?

Comment: See if that is any help

Comment: i don`t understand what to see ?

Comment: thanks a lot man, you are good, it`s works ! So that exit was the problem or ?

Comment: No I think the query not working was the problem so that the `if(isset($udata['ID']))` never got executed